# How to lock screen orientation in portrait on a IOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone

So I am developing an app on Intel XDK. This app requires the screen orientation to stay on portrait no matter what way the device is being held. I have googled this many times and nothing has come up for apps. If you could please show me how to do this that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use setRotateOrientation method or alternatively use the cordova-plugin-screen-orientation-master

```
intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation("portrait");
```

Comment: You would have to create a function `OnDeviceReady(){ intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation("portrait");} ` and then add an event listener `document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);` both of these should be placed within your HTML between script tags `<script> </script>`

Comment: So I did this in my code: '<script>
        OnDeviceReady(){ intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation("portrait");}
        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);
    </script>'